# Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerExceptionError: "connect timed out

Tags: sql-server, maven, jdbc, timeout

java program connects to the SQL server and tried to list tables from the database.
Got SQLServerException when I want to get a connection.

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost";
String username = "sa";
String password = "12345667";
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Below is the error message.

> Exception in thread "main"
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection
> to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed
> out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of
> SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at
> the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked
> by a firewall.".
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:227)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:284)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2435)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:635)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2010)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1687)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1528)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:866)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:569)
> at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
> at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)

Could anyone help me !!!!

Comment: Is your SQL Server instance actually listening on port 1433, and is access allowed by the firewall?

Comment: finally, I find the error. It is because I didn't restart the SQL server. And SQL browser was disabled. I reset them and it worked then. :D